# Flutter: set DropdownButtonFormField selection programatically

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to set the value of a DropdownButtonFormField programatically?
I tried manipulating the value property, but it does no show any effect.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TestPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  int _selectedId;
  List<Item> _items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      _items.add(Item(i, "choice " + i.toString()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButtonFormField(
            isExpanded: true,
            items: _items.map((item) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem(
                value: item.id,
                child: Text(item.text),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() => _selectedId = value);
            },
            value: _selectedId,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "select me",
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('set selected'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _selectedId = 3;
              });
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('get selected'),
            onPressed: () {
              print(_selectedId.toString());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  int id;
  String text;
  Item(this.id, this.text);
}
```

When setting _selectedId to 3 via the button, nothing happens, the dropdown does not update. If I set _selectedId to 3 on variable initialization, the third choice is selected when the page loads.
However I need it programatically.

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve? you want to only be able to set the new value when user clicks it from the drop down list and then click setSelected?

Comment: also, I tried to set it programmatically by copy pasting your code (and just changing color of text because it was white on a white background), and setting state worked by pressing the button

Comment: @LoVe
I have a dropdown list, where the user can add a new item if he wants to. Once he created his item, I want to select it automatically, so he does not have to click into the dropdown and search for the new item.
Adding the item to the list works fine, but selecting one programatically doesn't.

Comment: I copy-paste your code,and just changed text color,then pressed set selected, and the "item 3" appeared in the dropdown widget as the selected item,isn't this what you want?

Comment: @LoVe

Yes exactly, that's what I want. 
Why does it work with you, but not with me? Strange. What version of flutter do you use?

Comment: Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 • channel stable •

Comment: try restarting the whole app, it may be a problem in the hot reload maybe

Comment: @LoVe I restarted the app, but nope, did not help.
I use Channel master, v1.18.0-6.0.pre.70.

Maybe it's a bug in the newer version then.

Comment: works just fine: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vFHWkbtncW/ - Flutter 1.14.7-pre.83 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e10df3c1a6 (3 months ago) • 2020-02-01 11:23:01 +0800
Engine • revision e625e174c5
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.6.0 5ae5aff640)

Comment: I downgraded flutter to Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9.

But the problem persists. I tried it on an Android emulator (Pixel 2 with API 29).
I added the output of flutter doctor.

Comment: did you try the code i posted?

Comment: @pskink
I tried now, yes this seems to work. Not sure, why though ;-)

Comment: Ah, I see, I made a change to the code before downgrading. So it is indeed about the flutter version.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: not sure why? what you mean by that? basically you set `_selectedId` to 3 and rebuild the widget - this is normal, expected behavior

Comment: @pskink
Yes, it was because I'd made a change to my code before downgrading flutter. So I wondered, why mine was not working even with the older version, but your's did. But after I removed my change, it worked. So it must be definately a bug with the newer flutter version.